# vectorize a function with multiple variables

Tags: matlab, octave

Consider the arbitrary function:

```
function myFunc_ = myFunc(firstInput, secondInput)
    myFunc_ = firstInput * secondInput;
end
```

Now imagine I want to map the above function to an array for the first input `firstInput`, while the second input `secondInput` is constant. For example, something like:

```
firstVariable = linspace(0., 1.);

plot(firstVariable, map(myFunc, [firstVariable , 0.1]))
```

where `0.1` is an arbitrary scalar value for the `secondInput` and `firstVariable` array is an arbitrary array for the `firstInput`.

I have looked into the `arrayfun()` function. However, I don't know how to include the constant variable. Plus it seems like the syntax between MATLAB and Octave are different, or maybe I'm mistaken. It is important for me to have a cross-compatible code that I can share with colleagues.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by `map(fun, argv)`, but wouldn't `plot(firstVariable, myFunc(firstVariable, 0.1))` suffice?

Comment: @Vicky the `myFunc(firstVariable, 0.1))` returns a scalar in Octave. I don't know what it does on MATLAB though!

Comment: `myFunc(firstVariable, 0.1)` returns a vector in MATLAB!! What happens if you substitute an elementwise `.*` for the `*` in your function definition, does that make any difference? (https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming in the original function you were multiplying two scalars and you want to vectorise, then

```
function myFunc_ = myFunc(firstInput, secondInput)
    myFunc_ = firstInput .* secondInput;
end
```

should work just fine.

Then plot it directly:

```
plot( firstVariable, myFunc(firstVariable , 0.1) )
```

Comment: That's what I'd suspected from reading the docs!

Comment: No, I'm afraid the actual code is not as simple as the example given in the original question. I think I have found the right syntax that works on Octave. I will post it below for those who end up here.

Comment: Maybe I am making a mistake here, but I'm implementing equation 26 on [this paper](http://itzhak.green.gatech.edu/rotordynamics/POISSON%20RATIO%20EFFECTS%20AND%20CRITICAL%20VALUS%20IN%20SPHERICAL%20AND%20CYLINDRICAL.pdf). And I have indeed used the elementwise arithmetic operators in the actual code.

Comment: @Foad: There's no reason you wouldn't be able to trivially vectorize that equation. You'd compute each of the three components first, say `r1`, `r2` and `r3`, which would all be arrays, and then you compute `max(max(r1,r2),r3)` to find the element-wise max of the three. Computing `max([r1,r2,r3])` could result in a scalar.

Comment: that's basically what I did. I will publish the actual code on Github tomorrow night.

Comment: Actually I did publish the code on Github last night. [here the link](https://www.github.com/Foadsf/OpenHertz/tree/HTML/calculations%2FgreenShearStressLine.m)

Comment: @Foad: Change your `tmp0` function as I indicate in my comment above.

Comment: @CrisLuengo aha, so that was the problem! 

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the arbitrary examples given in the original question were too simplified and as a result, they do not represent the actual issue I'm facing with my code. But I did manage to find the right syntax that works inside Octave:

```
plot(firstVariable, arrayfun(@(tempVariable) myFunc(tempVariable, 0.1), firstVariable))
```

basically the

```
@(tempVariable) myFunc(tempVariable, 0.1)
```

creates what is so-called an anonymous function and the

```
arrayfun(<function>, <array>)
```

maps the function over the given array.